# Where are the logs to diagnose runtime behaviour of gluonfx apps on iOS

Tags: gluon-mobile

Environment is macOS 10.15.5, iOS 15.2 on iPad Pro. Encountering situations where a javafx app works fine with mvn gluonfx:run on macOS, then builds, packages and installs ok for iOS, but when run either with gluonfx:nativerun or launched from the iPad a black empty screen is presented.

I can go through regression approaches of removing change by change to help isolate which one is causing the issue, but due to native builds this is an extremely time consuming and ineffective way of trying to find out / learn what works ok on a jvm on macOS and not on compiled native code on iOS.

Looking through the various device logs with xcode I’m unable to find any run time diagnostic info, e.g. crash logs. Mvn gluonfx:nativerun doesn’t produce any additional info.

Am I looking in the wrong places, is there something I’m missing in terms of understanding how to see where stack traces or other stderr / stdout info might live while running on device, are there live debug capabilities or approaches while the native app is running on device that I haven’t discovered during all the reading of docs?

I’m confident this knowledge gap is entirely due to my newb status building javafx apps with gluon for this environment, there must be some way to collect runtime logs from the final app that I’ve missed.

Comment: Did you try to build the native image for desktop first? If that doesn't work, you need to fix the issues before building for iOS. Then for iOS, if it's native related, you might get a crash and a crash report, but if it is Java related, you won't, so it's better to add logs/system printouts and try-catch blocks to your code. `gluonfx:nativerun` from console will show everything that you are logging. Then there is the `Xcode->Window->Devices and Simulators->Open Console`, but that is way more verbose and it's harder to isolate your app native logs.

Comment: You are correct Jose, that a native build on macOS revealed graal was missing certain controllers, so the reflection files generated by runagent were picked up for the iOS build and it went well from there. There was nothing in crash reports or logs anywhere on the device to show the stack trace / missing code. I'm struggling to make nativerun work still, probably due to broken lib mobiledevice-glue packages.

Comment: If it is the first time installing libimobiledevice, it looks like the head versions are broken, try without head.

Comment: Thanks, that was the only way I found to get them installed, I started trying to build the broken dependencies manually and ran out of knowledge several steps in! Been capturing at https://medium.com/@alan.r.white/hacking-at-getting-a-macos-javafx-dev-setup-f1ac72ad3b69

Comment: Thanks for the link, good post! In case you want to have a look, this is the preview of the docs with the incoming changes once GluonFX 1.0.11 is released: https://docs.gluonhq.com/preview/100/#platforms_ios